Is it possible to set the optical size (opsz) of a font in Microsoft Word?
I'm using Microsoft Word for Mac Version 16.91 (24111020) and the ttf version of Newsreader and I want to use its optical sizes in Word.
There doesn't appear to be an obvious way to set the opsz axis of a font in Word using the normal UI. I'm wondering if there's a work-around or obscure feature I'm not finding by web search that would allow me to select an optical size.
(I'd rather be doing this in LaTeX, but unfortunately I'm stuck with Word for this project. If I can't select optical sizes in Word I wonder if there's a way to split the font differently named fonts for each weight and optical size.)

I would guess the precision of OPSZ is more about desktop publishing and precise layouts. Word has never been about desktop publishing, and so I would wager there is no method of doing what you want within that application.

@music2myear You're right about opsz, and in my current use-case it's just about making superscripts more readable. I'm looking for hacks to make Word do so even though it's not supported. Like, maybe an altered font name would trick it into using a different opsz -- or some kind of hack in that vein.

Instead of using a superscript, you can select the text you want to appear as if it were a superscript, right-click it, choose "Font...", select the "Advanced" tab, then, in the "Character Spacing" section, set the "Position" to "Raised" and enter a value in the adjacent "By" box. Maybe a style could be created from that to make it a little easier to use.

@AndrewMorton That might work well in another situation, but I need the superscripts to be a smaller font size as well, so optical sizing is really needed for decent readability. (And there are other cases when I want to be able to set opsz, for example using lighter optical sizes for headings and darker for smaller font size footnotes.) Really just looking for a hack to trick Word into using a different optical sizes.

You can also set the font size while you're doing the vertical offset. Not as clean as using TeX, of course; have you tried to find a LaTeX-to-Word convertor?
